# Behavioral model for single port RAM error on bidirectional inout port

Tags: verilog

Consider we have a single port 2^n*m bit RAM. Its description is as follows. It has an address port, enable port, an rw (read write) port and a bidirectional data port where you can read and write the data through it. My problem is I can't write through this port using my code so far:

```
module dual_port_ram # ( parameter n=4,m=4) (rw,addr,data,enable,clk);
  input rw,enable,clk;
  inout reg [m-1:0]data;
  input [n-1:0] addr;
  reg [m-1:0] ram [(2^n)-1:0]; 
  
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(enable) begin
      if(rw) 
        ram[addr]=data;// wrtite
        else
          data=ram[addr];// read
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Here is the error:

```
# SLP: Fatal Error: design.sv (3): Inout port 'data' of 'dual_port_ram' must be a net.
```

Comment: Note: `2^n` means "2 xor n", not "2 to the power n".  So, `2^4` is 6.  You likely meant to use `2**n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inout` ports are tricky.  Typically, you need to create a separate `reg` signal to assign to it, such as `data_reg`:

```
module dual_port_ram # ( parameter n=4,m=4) (rw,addr,data,enable,clk);
  input rw,enable,clk;
  inout [m-1:0] data;
  input [n-1:0] addr;
  reg [m-1:0] ram [(2^n)-1:0]; 
  
  reg [m-1:0] data_reg;

  assign data = (enable & !rw) ? data_reg : {m{1'bz}};

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(enable) begin
      if(rw) 
            ram[addr]=data;// write
        else
            data_reg=ram[addr];// read
    end
  end
endmodule
```